# Evaluation of thousands metrics in InfuxDB

Tags: database-performance, influxdb, evaluation, influxdb-2

I’m trying to evaluate thousands of metrics using a checkers, but my computer doesn’t count it. I tried tasks too.

PC: notebook with Core i5 (8 threads) and 16 GB RAM
I’m running influxdb in the docker (6 threads, 8 GB RAM is allowed).

Have you some idea where is problem?
Or influxdb can compute so many metrics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on influxdb community: https://community.influxdata.com/t/evaluation-of-thousands-metrics/19422